# What does »Guat« mean in this joke?

Tags: meaning, joke

The following short joke called [*Der Karabiner und der Gurt*](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/witz-19-der-karabiner-und-der-gurt-a-381829.html) comes from *Der Spiegel*:

> Sagt ein Gurt zum Karabiner: "Lass mich jetzt ja nicht hängen!" Sagt
>   der Karabiner zum Gurt: "Jo, Guat!"

What does the belt's answer to the carabiner mean?

Answer (score 7):

The pun here relies on the ambiguousness of *Guat*, which might be understood as:

- approximating regional (southern Bavarian, Austrian) pronounciation of *Gurt*
- regional pronounciation of *gut*, so *Jo, guat* [no reason for uppercase here, since no substantive] translates to *ja, [ist] gut*, a pretty standard response to a request.

Comment: Könnte hier auch "Yoghurt" im Spiel sein?

Comment: @Eller Könnte, aber was wäre der Zusammenhang zu Gurt und Karabiner?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ich hätte eher an Zusammenhang mit "hängen (lassen)" gedacht. Und wenn mir solcher Zusammenhang eingefallen wäre, hätte ich eine Antwort geschrieben.